# How to restrict the value range in dictionary?

Tags: python, variables, syntax

I'd like to impose restrictions on a value in a dictionary.
For example, assume that I have the following dictionary

```
speed = {
    'x': 8,
    'y': 0,
    'z': 4}
```

And I want the value corresponding to x-key in the speed dictionary always to be less than 10.
For example, if I use it in some funtion

```
    calcuate_speed(speed)
```

or
if I implement some mathematical transformation

```
    speed["x"] += 1
```

the value shouldn't be larger than a certain limit I defined.
What is the simplest way to handle it?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What is the "x-axis" considering you can only have 1 `x` key, and you're storing a scalar against it

Comment: you want to prevent such values from ever being set in the dictionary in the first place?

Comment: What do you want to achieve

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my question

Comment: why not create a class with x,y,z attributes instead?

Comment: I use this dictonary within a class I don't know if it is appropriate to create additional class for this problem

Comment: Tbh, it looks like self.speed

Comment: And I have a bunch of this kind dictionaries. Is it okey to create class for each one? Or should I incorporate all of them in one class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a next way:

```
from collections import UserDict


class MyDict(UserDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if value > 10: # any validation
            raise ValueError('Too big!')

        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

But it will be better to use a class with `property`.

Full version:

```
from collections import UserDict

from math import sqrt


class VectorDict(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, speed_limit, **kwargs):
        self.speed_limit = speed_limit
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if self._calc_speed(key, value) > self.speed_limit:
            raise ValueError('Too big!')

        super().__setitem__(key, value)

    def _calc_speed(self, replace_key=None, replace_value=0):
        square_sum = 0
        for key, value in self.items():
            if key == replace_key:
                value = replace_value

            square_sum += value ** 2

        return sqrt(square_sum)

    @property
    def speed(self):
        return self._calc_speed()


example_1d = VectorDict(x=1, speed_limit=5)
example_2d = VectorDict(x=1, y=5, speed_limit=7)
example_3d = VectorDict(x=1, y=5, z=3, speed_limit=13)

print(example_3d.speed)
example_3d['x'] += 10 # ValueError: Too big!
```

Comment: A class with property is an interesting option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add some value control in your cycle.
For example:

```
if (speed['x'] >= 10):
        speed['x'] = 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a class `MyClass` with a property `speed`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 0

    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        if k == 'speed' and v > 10: 
            return
        self.__dict__[k] = v
```

Here I'm just ignoring any changes to `speed` if it's not a valid value, but you can handle it differently as you per your needs (e.g. raise an exception)

Here's a demo:

```
m = MyClass()
m.speed = 8 
print(m.speed)
m.speed += 1
print(m.speed)
m.speed += 1
print(m.speed)
m.speed += 1
print(m.speed)
```

We get the following output:

```
8
9
10
10
```